# Connecting to VM services is taking longer than expected

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase, flutter, virtual-machine

I'm having an error while running a flutter app, it comes to the end but it gets stuck with VM Services, i have the GoogleService-Info.plist and everything okay, anybody now what might still be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can try adding `Firebase.initializeApp()` in the main.dart file. This solution worked for me.

If you cannot find `FirebaseApp` in your project then please add `firebase_core` in your `pub spec.yaml`.

Comment: I attempted this but didn't work, it says that FirebaseApp doesnt have any config() method, some recommended adding this to the appdelegate.swift file, i tried and didnt work either. I saw also some recommending to enable "iproxy" on settings, but i don't know where to find that i the settings of macos

Comment: Ok can you try by adding ```Firebase.initializeApp()``` ?

Answer (score 1):

Just Add `await Firebase.initializeApp();` Method in your main method, it will resolve your issue